# For what $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ is $\frac12(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$ an algebraic integer

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

I've recently been working on a practice midterm for my number theory class, and here is a problem I've come across. As there are no solutions posted, I'd like to verify that what I'm doing is actually on the right track.

> 6. Find all $a, b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\frac12(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$ is an algebraic integer.

First I set $x = \frac12(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)$, and after squaring both sides, moving over the $a,b$ term, and squaring again, I get:
$16x^4 -8x^2(a+b) + (a-b)^2 = 0$. Therefore, $\frac12(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)$ is algebraic iff $2\mid(a+b)$ and $4\mid(a-b)$

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: correct without any doubt

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments my answer seems to be correct above.

$\frac12(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)$ is algebraic iff 2|(a+b) and 4|(a-b)